# How does crypto library in Go compare to OpenSSL?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, go

Is it secure enough implementation to use in production code? Particularly as TLS client.

If not, is there documented method of calling OpenSSL library from Go?

Comment: Sorry what are you asking?

Comment: @haylem referred to the first entry [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Go's crypto package isn't vulnerable to this: http://heartbleed.com/

Comment: neither is openssl now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From http://blog.golang.org/a-conversation-with-the-go-team:

> *In the mailing lists Adam Langley has stated that the TLS code has not
>   been reviewed by outside groups, and thus should not be used in
>   production. Are there plans to have the code reviewed? A good secure
>   implementation of concurrent TLS would be very nice.*
>
> **Adam**: Cryptography is notoriously easy to botch in subtle and
>   surprising ways and I’m only human. I don’t feel that I can warrant
>   that Go’s TLS code is flawless and I wouldn’t want to misrepresent it.
>
> There are a couple of places where the code is known to have
>   side-channel issues: the RSA code is blinded but not constant time,
>   elliptic curves other than P-224 are not constant time and the Lucky13
>   attack might work. I hope to address the latter two in the Go 1.2
>   timeframe with a constant-time P-256 implementation and AES-GCM.
>
> Nobody has stepped forward to do a review of the TLS stack however and
>   I’ve not investigated whether we could get Matasano or the like to do
>   it. That depends on whether Google wishes to fund it.

It's known to be susceptible to certain side channel attacks, so no, it's probably not good enough yet.

Comment: For the record, Adam did address the points he mentioned in time for Go 1.2 (http://goo.gl/sY5ysT and http://goo.gl/wIfs5h).

Comment: Wondering about this in 2019

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, there are now high-performance bindings to OpenSSL from Go: https://github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl